# Error building wheel for manimpango

Tags: python3, pip

I use ubuntu and when I am getting error in installing manim,
`pip3 install manimpango` and `pip install manimpango` and have tried `sudo apt install libpango1.0-dev pkg-config python3-dev` but getting same error on `pip3 install manim`
the entire error [log file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b9lxrtbbj4itciw/manimpango%20%281%29.log?dl=0)

Comment: why are you trying to install the stuff for one user only?
Try `sudo pip3 install ..`

Comment: Hello. Since I can not login to your drop box there is no way for me or for that matter anyone else to read it. What version of Ubuntu are you using? What is the undefined error you are getting? Based on the info here its likely no one can assist you.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 :  "python3-pip" → `sudo pip install ManimPango` → Successfully built ManimPango ... Successfully installed ManimPango-0.4.1 → log.txt https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uV4koLwab_LvWOqAOLjQHwlYZra77lQH/view?usp=sharing